# Can I force debugging python on AssertionError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert, pdb

Suppose I have a python program where assert has been used to define how things should be, and I would like to capture anomalies with the read-eval-loop rather than having `AssertionError` be thrown.

Granted, I could have

```
if (reality!=expectation):
    print("assertion failed");
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
```

but that's far more ugly in the code than a plain `assert(reality==expectation)`.

I could have `pdb.set_trace()` called in an `except:` block at top-level, but then I'd have lost all the context of the failure, right ? (I mean, stacktrace could be recovered from the exception object, but not argument values, etc.)

Is there anything like a `--magic` command-line flag that could turn the python3 interpreter into what I need ?

Comment: use eclipse and run it in debug mode with a breakpoint ?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: You don't always have an IDE at hand. e.g: when you're logged on to a ssh shell.

Comment: then use pdb from the command line and use breakpoints... http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/pdb/  `python -m pdb somescript.py` is your `--magic`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I don't think that this is what the OP wants. He wants to start the debugger on *any* exception, not just on the breakpoints he has to set *manually*.

Comment: wont pdb drop you into interactive debug mode on any exception? at least any exception that would break execution?

Comment: @joran: eclipse is not an option in this context, unfortunately. Plus, setting breakpoints on all asserts would be tedious, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Hmm ... I wouldn't have imagined that some modules could behave as pdb does. Are there other such "impossible-to-miss" modules that I should have a look at ?

Answer (score 15):

Mainly taken from [this great snippet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65287-automatically-start-the-debugger-on-an-exception/):

```
import sys

def info(type, value, tb):
    if hasattr(sys, 'ps1') or not sys.stderr.isatty() or type != AssertionError:
        # we are in interactive mode or we don't have a tty-like
        # device, so we call the default hook
        sys.__excepthook__(type, value, tb)
    else:
        import traceback, pdb
        # we are NOT in interactive mode, print the exception...
        traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
        print
        # ...then start the debugger in post-mortem mode.
        pdb.pm()

sys.excepthook = info
```

When you initialize your code with this, all `AssertionError`s should invoke pdb.

Comment: I suppose "post-mortem mode" is mandatory here, and there's no chance `pdb.set_trace()` would be any useful, would it ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure here, I guess you have to try.

Comment: tried and dropped: it works, but you're debugging in a sort of "top-level frame", not in the frame that thrown the assertion error ... that makes it pretty useless.

Comment: @sylvainulg: I just checked the docs (http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) and it seems that the exception is already uncaught at this point. So `set_trace()` would not help in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org) project. You can use it with the [--pdb option](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#cmdoption--pdb) to drop into the debugger on errors.

Comment: I suppose that's handy for those who do unit testing, but that's not what I'm doing here.

Comment: Be aware that the nose project is by now in maintenance mode